# Get the values from the html.Append() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i have this code in Code Behind in c# for `aspx` file and i don't know how to get the value.

**Code Behind:**

```
 html.Append("<input type='radio' name='radioButton' id='radioButton' runat='server' value='"+ data +"'/>");
```

i usually do for the aspx code to get the value is that i add an attribute `runat="server"` and call it in the code behind. can someone help me how to get the value in the `radioButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have direct access in code behind because if you add line by html.append radio button are not appear in designer class by default. It's little problematic solution. Better idea is to add this line in .aspx file with visible attribute:

```
<input type='radio' name='radioButton' id='radioButton' runat='server' visible="false"/>
```

In code behind you can call radioButton.Value to set value and than set radioButton.Visible to true to show on page. If you need multiple radiobuttons use repeater control and bind this control with collection of your values.

Comment: i have a code sir for making a table and display it using html.Apped() function  

`foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        string data = Convert.ToString(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        html.Append("<td>");
                        if (column.ColumnName == "OfferCode")
                            html.Append("<input type='radio' name='radioButton' id='radioButton' runat='server' value='"+ data +"'/>");
                        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                        html.Append("</td>");
                    }`

Comment: Why you cannot use gridview? You can bind gridview with your DataTable dt.